# Is it possible to run a plugin in between two executions of another plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

For explanation purposes, assume I would like to:

- copy project artifact jar (maven-antrun-plugin)
- copy dependencies (maven-dependency-plugin)
- compile installer (maven-antrun-plugin)

Unfortunately both maven-antrun-plugin executions are run together. There is a warning about duplicate plugin declaration, and they are merged together in the effective POM.

Edit:
This specific task could be solved by using other phases or the install4j plugin, but I am interested whether it is generally possible to execute e.g. maven-antrun-plugin multiple times during the same phase in a specific order (with other plugins in between).

```
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <!-- copy project jar -->
      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-project-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <copy file="target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                  tofile="target/installer/bin/${project.artifactId}.jar" />
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <!-- copy dependencies -->
      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/installer/bin</outputDirectory>
              <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <!-- compile installer -->
      <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-installer</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <exec executable="${install4j.home}/bin/install4jc.exe">
                  <arg value="installer.install4j" />
                </exec>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Merged effective POM:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-project-artifact</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <copy file="target/test-1.0.0.jar" tofile="target/installer/bin/test.jar" />
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-installer</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <exec executable="C:\Program Files\install4j8/bin/install4jc.exe">
                  <arg value="installer.install4j" />
                </exec>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken things but why isn't a maven plugin being used ? https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/maven.html

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, the install4j plugin could be used for this specific task. but it is meant more as an example to explain my question

Comment: The only way to get a plugin running is to bind that plugin into a different life cycle phase...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to put all executions into the same plugin definition.

Secondly, I doubt that this is possible, but usually you can split things up by using more phases. E.g. you could use `prepare-package` for the first execution of the antrun plugin.

Comment: Yes, I see how using other phases would work for the given example.